# BottomSheetDialog background transparency MAUI

Tags: android, .net, cross-platform, maui, android-bottomsheetdialog

I create a plataform specific class for create a bottomsheetDialog in android.

```
public void ShowBottomSheet(Page page, IView bottomSheetContent, bool dimDismiss)
{
     var bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.Current);
     var view = bottomSheetContent.ToContainerView(page.Handler?.MauiContext ?? throw new Exception("MauiContext is null"));
     bottomSheetDialog.SetContentView(view);
     bottomSheetDialog.Show(); 
}
```

The problem is that i cant set background tranparency. I cant remove this portion of top of my bottomsheet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7M0s.png)

obs.: I set ContentPage of ("bottomSheetContent") with transparency too

Some idea?
ty

Comment: `I cant remove the with portion of top of my bottomsheet.` I don't quite understand the meaning of above sentence. Can you explain in detail which part of the screenshot the problem is?  In addition, if it is convenient for you, could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: This is my project that i use for lern .NET MAUI :) [git](https://github.com/flipper09112/HeartsCounter)
The problem is that i use AddRoundBottomSheetView.xaml with frame with corners for use in HeartsCounter/HeartsCounter/Platforms/Android/ServiceBottomSheetDialogService.cs but corners still appear in BottomSheetDialog

Comment: Sorry , I couldn't open the link you posted above.

Comment: https://github.com/flipper09112/HeartsCounter

Comment: I deployed your code to my device, but  I didn't find the  page where this problem occurred.